# Polynomials and the fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p(z) = z^n + a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + ... + a_0 = 0 $ be a polynomial. first, I want to show that there exists numbers $\alpha, \beta $ such that $|z| > \beta \implies |p(z)| > \alpha $

I am having hard time trying to find this bounds. My idea is to suppose $\beta = 1$ so that $|z| > 1$. Then, we would have $|z|^n > |z| $ for all $n > 1 $. Can we conclude from here that there is some $\alpha $ such that $|p(z)| > \alpha $??

Also, how can we find a $z_0$ such that $p(z_0) = \min_{z \in \mathbb{C}} |p(z)| $?

Comment: I think you have an extraneous $=0$ in the first sentence. Also, since $p$ is complex valued, it doesn't make sense to take the $\min$.

Comment: sorry, it should the min of $|p(z)|$

Comment: Well, since $p$ is a polynomial it has a zero, hence let $z_0$ be any zero of $p$. Are you asking how to find a root in general?

Comment: yes. the goal is to show this $z_0$ is actually a root of $p$.

Comment: Are you trying to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $p(z) = z^n r(z)$, where $r(z) = 1+ {a_{n-1} \over z} + \cdots + {a_0 \over z^n}$.
If $|z| \ge 2 n \max(1, |a_{n-1}|, \cdots, |a_0| ) $, then $|r(z)| \ge {1 \over 2}$, and so
$|p(z)| \ge {1 \over 2} |z|^n \ge {1 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\lim_{|z|\to\infty } \left|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{a_{n-1-j}}{z^{j+1}}\right| =0$$ hence for sufficiency large $|z|$ we have $$\left|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{a_{n-1-j}}{z^{j+1}}\right| <2^{-1}$$ so $$|p(z)| =|z|^n \cdot \left|1+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{a_{n-1-j}}{z^{j+1}}\right|\geq |z|^n \left(1-\left|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{a_{n-1-j}}{z^{j+1}}\right|\right) \geq 2^{-1} |z|^n$$
sufficiency large $|z|.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\begin{align}
|z^n| = |p(z) - a_{n-1}z^{n-1} - \cdots - a_0| &\leq |p(z)| + |a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0| \\
&\leq |p(z)| + |a_{n-1}z^{n-1}| + \cdots + |a_0| \\
\end{align}$$
so
$$|p(z)| \geq |z^n| - |a_{n-1}z^{n-1}| - \cdots - |a_0|$$
Now suppose that
$$|z| \geq \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} \left|2n a_{n-k}\right|^{1/k} := M$$
Then the following inequality holds for each $k \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$:
$$|a_{n-k}| \leq \frac{|z^k|}{2n}$$
and as a result,
$$|a_{n-k}z^{n-k}| \leq \frac{|z^n|}{2n}$$
Therefore,
$$|p(z)| \geq |z^n| - n\frac{|z^n|}{2n} = \frac{|z^n|}{2} \geq \frac{M^n}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that $p(z)=0$ which implies that $|p(z)|=0$. Then for any $\beta$ with $|z|>\beta$ is impossible to find $\alpha$ such that $|p(z)|> \alpha$ with $\alpha>0$. Such an $\alpha$ must be negative, but this conclusion is obvious from the beginning. 
For the last question, you have to be more specific with the notation $$p(z_0) = \min_{z \in \mathbb{C}} p(z),$$ because in the set of complex numbers the relation "less than" has no sense.